# Can we reduce ESP IDF boiler plate size?

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I tested running bare bones code using ESP IDF on an ESP32 chip using duinotech XC-3800, and obtained the following results in terms of image size.

## Analysis Binary Size for ESP32

### Folder Structure

- temp/

  - main/

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - main.c
  - CMakeLists.txt

### File contents

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
# The following lines of boilerplate have to be in your project's
# CMakeLists in this exact order for cmake to work correctly
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(temp)
```

#### main>CMakeLists.txt

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "main.c"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS "")
```

#### Test 1 main>main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void app_main(void) {
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("Restarting in %d seconds...\n", i);
  }
  printf("Restarting now.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

#### Test 2 main>main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void app_main(void) { printf("Hello world!\n"); }
```

#### Test 3 main>main.c

```
void app_main(void) {}
```

### Size comparison

Obtained by running `idf_size.py build/temp.map`

#### Test 1

```
Total sizes:
 DRAM .data size:    8320 bytes
 DRAM .bss  size:    4072 bytes
Used static DRAM:   12392 bytes ( 168344 available, 6.9% used)
Used static IRAM:   38804 bytes (  92268 available, 29.6% used)
      Flash code:   75408 bytes
    Flash rodata:   23844 bytes
Total image size:~ 146376 bytes (.bin may be padded larger)
```

#### Test 2

```
Total sizes:
 DRAM .data size:    8320 bytes
 DRAM .bss  size:    4072 bytes
Used static DRAM:   12392 bytes ( 168344 available, 6.9% used)
Used static IRAM:   38804 bytes (  92268 available, 29.6% used)
      Flash code:   75240 bytes
    Flash rodata:   23796 bytes
Total image size:~ 146160 bytes (.bin may be padded larger)
```

#### Test 3

```
Total sizes:
 DRAM .data size:    8320 bytes
 DRAM .bss  size:    4072 bytes
Used static DRAM:   12392 bytes ( 168344 available, 6.9% used)
Used static IRAM:   38804 bytes (  92268 available, 29.6% used)
      Flash code:   75004 bytes
    Flash rodata:   23780 bytes
Total image size:~ 145908 bytes (.bin may be padded larger)
```

### Analysis

Size for code obtained by running `stat --format="%s" main/main.c`

All Sizes are in Bytes

```
Test No. | Code |  Image | Flash Code | Flash rodata
-------- | -----| ------ | ---------- | ------------
       1 |  207 | 146376 |      75408 |        23844
       2 |   70 | 146160 |      75240 |        23796
       3 |   43 | 145908 |      75004 |        23780
```

At least 145KB of boiler plate code just to get an empty main run.

### Speculation

I suspect that the 145KB is made up of a number of libraries that are always loaded onto the chip whether you use them or not. Some of them must be the `FreeRTOS`, `WiFi`, `HTTP` etc.

Can we bring down this size somehow and load only the bare minimum required for operation?

Answer (score 3):

You can get more detailed size information by running `idf.py size-components` and `idf.py size-files`. Here are the results for your "Test 3" (i.e. empty function) on my dev environment (note that my `Total Image Size` is already slightly larger than the one you posted.

```
Total sizes:
 DRAM .data size:    7860 bytes
 DRAM .bss  size:    4128 bytes
Used static DRAM:   11988 bytes ( 168748 available, 6.6% used)
Used static IRAM:   32706 bytes (  98366 available, 25.0% used)
      Flash code:   76002 bytes
    Flash rodata:   32164 bytes
Total image size:~ 148732 bytes (.bin may be padded larger)
Per-archive contributions to ELF file:
            Archive File DRAM .data & .bss   IRAM Flash code & rodata   Total
                  libc.a          0      0      0      55348     3829   59177
              libesp32.a       2132   2351   6767       5976     8076   25302
           libfreertos.a       4140    776  12432          0     1653   19001
             libdriver.a         76     20      0       4003     7854   11953
                libsoc.a        161      4   4953        612     3852    9582
                libvfs.a        240    103      0       5464      950    6757
               libheap.a        877      4   3095        830      986    5792
          libspi_flash.a         24    290   1855        779      890    3838
              libefuse.a         16      4      0       1142     2213    3375
             libnewlib.a        152    272    766        830       96    2116
         libapp_update.a          0      4    109        159     1221    1493
        libesp_ringbuf.a          0      0    848          0      209    1057
                liblog.a          8    268    429         82        0     787
                libhal.a          0      0    515          0       32     547
            libpthread.a          8     12      0        256        0     276
                libgcc.a          0      0      0          0      160     160
 libbootloader_support.a          0      0      0        126        0     126
                  libm.a          0      0      0         88        0      88
                libcxx.a          0      0      0         11        0      11
libxtensa-debug-module.a          0      0      8          0        0       8
               libmain.a          0      0      0          5        0       5
                   (exe)          0      0      0          0        0       0
         libmbedcrypto.a          0      0      0          0        0       0
            libmbedtls.a          0      0      0          0        0       0
     libwpa_supplicant.a          0      0      0          0        0       0
Per-file contributions to ELF file:
             Object File DRAM .data & .bss   IRAM Flash code & rodata   Total
        lib_a-vfprintf.o          0      0      0      14193      756   14949
       lib_a-svfprintf.o          0      0      0      13838      756   14594
      lib_a-svfiprintf.o          0      0      0       9642     1210   10852
       lib_a-vfiprintf.o          0      0      0       9945      738   10683
              uart.c.obj         44     12      0       2985     7293   10334
             tasks.c.obj         12    700   5546          0      531    6789
          vfs_uart.c.obj         48     63      0       3680      808    4599
             panic.c.obj       2023      5   1989          0        0    4017
   esp_err_to_name.c.obj          0      0      0         50     3947    3997
           portasm.S.obj       3084      0    484          0        0    3568
            lib_a-dtoa.o          0      0      0       3522       13    3535
        multi_heap.c.obj        873      0   2277          0        0    3150
        intr_alloc.c.obj          8     22    618       1703      722    3073
 esp_efuse_utility.c.obj          0      0      0        867     2205    3072
         cpu_start.c.obj          0      1   1068        331     1352    2752
             queue.c.obj          0      0   2310          0      325    2635
           lib_a-mprec.o          0      0      0       2134      296    2430
           rtc_clk.c.obj        161      4   2098          0        0    2263
         dbg_stubs.c.obj          0   2072     32        108        0    2212
               vfs.c.obj        192     40      0       1784      142    2158
        rtc_periph.c.obj          0      0      0          0     2080    2080
   esp_timer_esp32.c.obj          8     26   1068        262      538    1902
    xtensa_vectors.S.obj          8      0   1776          0       36    1820
        flash_mmap.c.obj          0    264   1092        114      339    1809
          task_wdt.c.obj         53      4      0       1178      548    1783
         heap_caps.c.obj          4      0    818         52      617    1491
            timers.c.obj          8     56   1006          0      233    1303
       cache_utils.c.obj          4     14    749         81      402    1250
 soc_memory_layout.c.obj          0      0      0          0     1181    1181
    heap_caps_init.c.obj          0      4      0        778      369    1151
              port.c.obj          0     16    625          0      493    1134
       esp_ota_ops.c.obj          0      4      0        147      965    1116
   xtensa_intr_asm.S.obj       1024      0     51          0        0    1075
           ringbuf.c.obj          0      0    848          0      209    1057
          rtc_time.c.obj          0      0    815          0      198    1013
memory_layout_utils.c.ob          0      0      0        612      393    1005
          rtc_init.c.obj          0      0    992          0        0     992
       periph_ctrl.c.obj          8      0      0        615      280     903
          lib_a-fseeko.o          0      0      0        866        0     866
              time.c.obj          0     32    122        703        0     857
               clk.c.obj          0      0     64        559      221     844
         esp_timer.c.obj          8     16    261        406      134     825
      dport_access.c.obj          8     40    444        189      137     818
               log.c.obj          8    268    429         82        0     787
           rtc_wdt.c.obj          0      0    743          0        0     743
         partition.c.obj          0      8      0        522      149     679
               ipc.c.obj          0     28    159        283      120     590
             locks.c.obj          8      0    485          0       94     587
     crosscore_int.c.obj          8      8    193        130      156     495
     syscall_table.c.obj        144    240      0         82        0     466
        system_api.c.obj          0      0    439          0        0     439
             timer.c.obj         16      0      0        112      281     409
           int_wdt.c.obj          0      1     91        306        0     398
    freertos_hooks.c.obj          8    128     43        216        0     395
      esp_app_desc.c.obj          0      0    109         12      256     377
          brownout.c.obj          0      0      0        149      201     350
       windowspill_asm.o          0      0    311          0        0     311
        rtc_module.c.obj          8      8      0        291        0     307
    xtensa_context.S.obj          0      0    306          0        0     306
          cpu_util.c.obj          0      0    305          0        0     305
dport_panic_highint_hdl.          8      0    242          0        0     250
           lib_a-reent.o          0      0      0        232        0     232
           lib_a-fopen.o          0      0      0        224        0     224
        lib_a-snprintf.o          0      0      0        214        0     214
     esp_efuse_api.c.obj          0      4      0        193        0     197
pthread_local_storage.c.          8      4      0        180        0     192
     cache_err_int.c.obj          0      0     56         98        0     154
       xtensa_intr.c.obj          0      0    108          0       35     143
              list.c.obj          0      0    142          0        0     142
          syscalls.c.obj          0      0     91         45        0     136
          lib_a-assert.o          0      0      0         68       60     128
           lib_a-flags.o          0      0      0        127        0     127
 bootloader_common.c.obj          0      0      0        126        0     126
         lib_a-s_frexp.o          0      0      0        110        0     110
         flash_ops.c.obj         20      4     14         62        0     100
         lib_a-vprintf.o          0      0      0         94        0      94
    lib_a-s_fpclassify.o          0      0      0         88        0      88
        lib_a-fiprintf.o          0      0      0         84        0      84
           pthread.c.obj          0      8      0         76        0      84
  esp_efuse_fields.c.obj          0      0      0         82        0      82
                 clock.o          0      0     72          0        0      72
        reent_init.c.obj          0      0     68          0        2      70
state_asm--restore_extra          0      0     62          0        0      62
state_asm--save_extra_nw          0      0     62          0        0      62
xtensa_vector_defaults.S          0      0     46          0        0      46
           lib_a-fseek.o          0      0      0         45        0      45
               _divdi3.o          0      0      0          0       40      40
               _moddi3.o          0      0      0          0       40      40
              _udivdi3.o          0      0      0          0       40      40
              _umoddi3.o          0      0      0          0       40      40
       xtensa_init.c.obj          0      4     32          0        0      36
  interrupts--intlevel.o          0      0      0          0       32      32
   esp_efuse_table.c.obj         16      0      0          0        8      24
           lib_a-errno.o          0      0      0         10        0      10
          pm_esp32.c.obj          0      0      0          8        0       8
 int_asm--set_intclear.o          0      0      8          0        0       8
               eri.c.obj          0      0      8          0        0       8
cxx_exception_stubs.cpp.          0      0      0          6        0       6
      cxx_guards.cpp.obj          0      0      0          5        0       5
  hello_world_main.c.obj          0      0      0          5        0       5
  FreeRTOS-openocd.c.obj          4      0      0          0        0       4
    dummy_main_src.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
  bootloader_flash.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
 bootloader_random.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
    bootloader_sha.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
  esp_image_format.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
  flash_partitions.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
           lib_a-fputs.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
          lib_a-printf.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
            lib_a-putc.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
         lib_a-putchar.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
            lib_a-puts.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
         lib_a-sprintf.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
        lib_a-strerror.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
        lib_a-u_strerr.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
  lib_a-xpg_strerror_r.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
              gpio.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
         hw_random.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
          pm_locks.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
            _addsubdf3.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
               _cmpdf2.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
               _divdf3.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
              _fixdfsi.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
            _floatdidf.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
            _floatsidf.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
               _muldf3.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
          _popcountsi2.o          0      0      0          0        0       0
          platform.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
     platform_util.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
            sha256.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
           esp_mem.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
       gpio_periph.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
spi_flash_rom_patch.c.ob          0      0      0          0        0       0
      md5-internal.c.obj          0      0      0          0        0       0
```

From a library point of view, the major contributor is `libc` which is the C standard library. While you could probably cherry-pick some functions and drop others from there, I don't think anyone would recommend that.

Next up is `libesp32`, which provides critical functions such as `start_cpu0()`. Again, you may be able to cherry-pick only the functions you need, if you really want to.

You can figure out what a library provides by looking up the `.a` file (e.g. `find build -name libesp32.a`, and then running `nm build/esp-idf/esp32/libesp32.a` on the found path.

The second table lists the same size-data, but split per source-file instead of per library.